# Read from input-port blocks when char is ready

Tags: io, scheme, racket, blocking

I don't understand why my code doesn't work. I have a vector, this vector contains `input-ports` on certain locations and `0` on other locations. When there is an `input port`, I want to check if there is data available. If there is data available, read it and enqueue it. If there isn't, move on.

Here's my code:

```
;The name of the vector is 'in'.
(define (read-ports)
  (let loop
    ((idx 0))
    (if (not (= idx (vector-length in)))
        (let ((port (vector-ref in idx)))
          (if (not (eq? port 0))
              (if (char-ready? port)
                  (let ((data (read port)))
                    (sendm buffer 'enqueue! data)) ;my own queue
                  (loop (+ idx 1)))
              (loop (+ idx 1))))
        'done)))
```

My problem is, `char-ready` returns `true`, but the `read` operation still blocks! I'm sure the data is being send, but then why does it block? The data I am trying to send are `vectors`, but these contain values between 0 en 255. So actually they are `vectors` of `bytes`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `char-ready?` is true if you can use `read-byte`, not `read`.

Comment: Is there something I can use to check if `read` is going to block?

Comment: Are you sure you need `read`? I would look into the `read-bytes-*` and `peek-*` procedures.

Comment: Also, you can greatly simplify your code using `for` loops or `for-each`.

Comment: I'm sending `vectors`. But these contain values between 0 en 255, so `bytes` essentially. Can I read these vectors-of-bytes with `read-bytes` or do I have to cast them to something else?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as-asked:

`read` blocks until it can read a *complete* s-expression. As a result, if you are trying to read the vector `#(1 2 3 4)`, the bytes for the `#(1 2` part may be available to read now -- but not necessarily the bytes for the remaining `3 4)`.

---

To make a general suggestion:

Although I don't know the context of what you want to accomplish, it sounds like you have N `input-port`s, and your `read-ports` function will try to read a `vector` from each port, putting the result in some central `buffer`, then return `'done`.  (I'm not sure if you will call `read-ports` once, or repeatedly.)

A better design *probably* would be to make a `thread` to read each `port`, and have each thread put its result in a central buffer by using an async-channel to guard/coordinate access to that buffer. So you'd have N threads, each reading one of the N ports.

This way, you don't need to worry about blocking -- each thread calls `read`, and it is done when it is done. (OTOH this design would mean the vectors could be read out of order; if that matters, you could handle it in a few ways.)

Again, I don't know your exact goal, but basically I'm suggesting to work "with" Racket by using its lightweight green threads and channels.

Comment: I was using threads to do this, but I need to remove these from my code.